# How to solve undefined reference cv:.... when compiling openCV application in Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, undefined-reference

I managed to build OpenCV (version 4.0.0) in a local folder in a OSX environment following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651362/how-to-include-and-use-opencv-library-when-installed-locally).

I tried the same steps in Linux and Ubuntu and did

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../your/path/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Everything looks fine but when I try to compile a test project with the `Makefile` I posted in the question I get this errrors

```
/tmp/ccVvPXNi.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccVvPXNi.o: In function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_[_ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_]+0x28): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'test.o' failed
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

and with the following `Makefile` I get much more undefined references:

```
CPP = g++

# OpenCV trunk
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++11  \
           `pkg-config --cflags --libs ../cmake_bin_dir/instDir/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc`

# Opencv 2.4.8
#CPPFLAGS = -L/home/krystof/libs/opencv-2.4.8/release/installed/libs \
       -I/home/krystof/libs/opencv-2.4.8/release/installed/include

all: provaMat

provaMat.o: provaMat.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

I get the following errors in this case:

```
/tmp/ccwJs00N.o: In function `main':
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)'
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)'
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0x1c5): undefined reference to `cv::GaussianBlur(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, double, double, int)'
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0x245): undefined reference to `cv::Canny(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, double, int, bool)'
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0x2d3): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0x322): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
provaMat.cpp:(.text+0x41b): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
/tmp/ccwJs00N.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
provaMat.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2EPKc[_ZN2cv6StringC5EPKc]+0x54): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccwJs00N.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
provaMat.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccwJs00N.o: In function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
provaMat.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_[_ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_]+0x28): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccwJs00N.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
provaMat.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccwJs00N.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
provaMat.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x4b): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'provaMat.o' failed
make: *** [provaMat.o] Error 1
```

What step am I missing? Does anyone have a suggestion?

EDIT:
The result of `pkg-config --cflags --libs ../cmake_bin_dir/instDir/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc` is

```
-I/root/openCV4/cmake_bin_dir/instDir/include/opencv -I/root/openCV4/cmake_bin_dir/instDir/include -L/root/openCV4/cmake_bin_dir/instDir/lib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the recipe for `provaMat.o` to the following:

```
provaMat.o: provaMat.cpp
    $(CPP) $^ $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@
```

For a while now the default linker options used by GCC include the `--as-needed` flag. This makes the linker discard any objects that are never referenced at the point where they appear in the command line. So if a library appears before any reference to its symbols, it is completely discarded.

It may make sense to change the rule to the following and put all library related flags in a `LIBS` variable.

```
provaMat.o: provaMat.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I was really going crazy. But why the g++ on MacOS works in the other way and the one in Ubuntu does not?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi: MacOS uses a different object and executable format than Linux, MachO instead of elf, and thus needs a different linker. Maybe the MacOS linker has no `--as-needed` option, or it is named differently and nobody bothered to enable it. Also, the version of gcc is probably different.